# What is the difference between ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); and ArrayList al = new ArrayList(0)?

Tags: java

What is the difference between ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); and ArrayList al = new ArrayList(0)?

Comment: `new ArrayList()` is equivalent to (and probably implemented in terms of) `new ArrayList(10)`

Comment: May be a difference on memory allocation by JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look on the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), it says, 
ArrayList() - Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

ArrayList(int initialCapacity) - Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Comment: in (open) JDK8, this seems to be not the case. It _does say_ that it creates an initial capacity of 10, but in fact it creates a capacity of 0: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28%29

Answer (score 6):

```
ArrayList(0)
```

Empty list with the specified initial capacity. Hense none for 0

```
ArrayList()
```

Empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

Please read the following: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

new ArrayList() gives you an array list with default initial capacity (how much memory is initially allocated from the ArrayList). 
new ArrayList(0) gives you an array list with zero initial capacity. As soon as an element is added to the list, capacity is allocated.