# Android, sending XML string to server via HTTP

Tags: java, android, xml, http, post

I have recently started doing Android programming. I have come across a problem. Currently I have built a XML string request called 'sendData'. This sendData needs to be sent to the server to validate if the user account is valid or not.

Currently when I try to send the request, I make contact with the server, but I get a default generic response error back which makes me believe that the XML isn't being sent correcrtly.

```
public void postData(String sendData) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        System.out.println("SENDDATA" + sendData);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www......");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(0);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(sendData, sendData));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

The above is the code I am using to send the data. I believe the problem is happening within the 'try' section, possibly. I have searched for similar problems on this forum and cannot find the answer I was looking for.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT:

In the log cat. When I print the string off, it looks like this.

```
07-19 15:35:36.642: INFO/System.out(2204): <Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.example.com">
07-19 15:35:36.642: INFO/System.out(2204): <Identification>
07-19 15:35:36.642: INFO/System.out(2204): <UserID>username@example.com</UserID>
07-19 15:35:36.642: INFO/System.out(2204): <Password>password</Password>
07-19 15:35:36.642: INFO/System.out(2204): </Identification>
07-19 15:35:36.642: INFO/System.out(2204): <Service>
07-19 15:35:36.652: INFO/System.out(2204): <ServiceName>AccountVerify</ServiceName>
07-19 15:35:36.652: INFO/System.out(2204): <ServiceDetail/>
07-19 15:35:36.652: INFO/System.out(2204): </Service>
```

07-19 15:35:36.652: INFO/System.out(2204):

Each element has it's own line in the LogCat. Could this be the problem?

Comment: 1.) Post the error message you are getting. 2.) Put something in the catch blocks - errors may be getting caught, hitting the empty catch block and showing nothing, and then the program continues on in a bad state.

Comment: Have you tried using TCPMon to intercept and verify the data being from your app?

Comment: I don't recieve any error messages. I will and put something in the catch blocks. I have never used TCPMon but I will look into it.

Comment: I have checked the catch's. Nothing is being caught, so no errors are being thrown whatsoever.

Comment: have you figure out the problem yet?

Comment: Yes thank you. I have posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got to the answer. The problem was that no information was being sent in the actual request upon looking further. The solution was to remove the array and replace it by setting a new Entity. The changed / working code is below:

```
        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(sendData);
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println("Message Sent!");
            inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you use [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com) to help you detect what you are sending.  This is a great tool and will save you a lot of time.

There are a couple of <strike>errors</strike> issues with the code you have posted.

The arraylist you are creating has a size of 0, this would be more efficient to set to 1 (as you are adding only one NameValuePair

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
```

The first BasicNameValuePair constructor parameter is wrong and    should be some kind of key name

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mySendData", sendData));
```

Comment: actually ArrayList<...>(0) is ok ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666024/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylist-al-new-arraylist-and-arraylist-al ... but you're right about BasicNameValuePair :)