# Advantages of creating an ArrayList with initial capacity of 0?

Tags: java, arraylist, capacity

I am a somewhat experienced Java developer and I keep seeing things like this

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
```

which I really can't understand. What's the point of creating an `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of 0, when you know it's going to grow beyond the capacity?

Are there any known benefits of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); and ArrayList al = new ArrayList(0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666024/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylist-al-new-arraylist-and-arraylist-al)

Comment: Also: [Why start an ArrayList with an initial capacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430247/why-start-an-arraylist-with-an-initial-capacity)

Comment: @Ascalonian I actually do know the difference, what I want to know is the advantage of doing so instead of doing `new ArrayList<Integer>()`. Not a dup.

Comment: See the second link I provided

Comment: @Ascalonian barq answer still seems more appropriate. I stumbled upon the second link but it's still not what I wanted to know.

Comment: Then you have your answer :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It keeps the size (in memory) of the `ArrayList` very small, and is a tactic for when you want the variable to be non-null and ready to use, but don't *expect* for the `List` to be populated immediately. If you expect it to be populated immediately, it's best to give it a larger initial value - any "growing" of the `ArrayList` is internally creating a new primitive array, and copying items over. Growth of an `ArrayList` is expensive, and should be minimized.

Or, if you're creating *lots* of instances of a class that each contain one of these `List` properties. If you don't immediately plan on filling them, you can save a bit of memory by not allocating the room just yet.

**However:** There is a better way: `Collections.emptyList()`. Normally you'll want to protect access to that list directly, and (as an example) in your class provide domain-specific method calls that operate on the internal `List`. For example, let's say you have a `School` class that contains a `List` of student names. (Keeping it simple, note this class is **not thread safe.**)

```
public class School {
    private List<String> studentNames = Collections.emptyList();

    public void addStudentName(String name) {
        if (studentNames.isEmpty()) {
            studentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        studentNames.add(name);
    }

    public void removeStudentName(String name) {
        studentNames.remove(name);
        if (studentNames.isEmpty()) {
            studentNames = Collections.emptyList(); // GC will deallocate the old List
        }
    }
}
```

If you're willing to make the `isEmpty()` checks and perform the initialization/assignment, this is a better alternative to creating lots of empty `ArrayList` instances, as `Collections.emptyList()` is a static instance (only one exists) and is not modifiable.

Answer (score 8):

For java **6** (or openjdk 7), not specifying an initial size gives you a list within initial size set to *10*. So depending on many factors of your usage of the list, it could be very slightly more memory and/or performance efficient to initialize the list with size `0`.

For java **7**, specifying an initial size `0` is functionally equivalent to not specifying an initial size.

However it is actually less efficient, since the call to the constructor with argument `0` incurs a call to `new Object[0]`, whereas if you specify the no-args constructor, the initial `elementData` for your list is set to a statically defined constant named `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA`.

Relevant code from `ArrayList` source:

```
/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for empty instances.
 */
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

In other words the use of `new ArrayList<Integer>(0);` seems superfluous, there are no benefits to doing so, and I would use `new ArrayList<Integer>();` instead.

Comment: That's true for openjdk 7. Not true for open jdk 6 see -> http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java/?v=source

Comment: And it's not even true for *all* versions of OpenJDK 7, it seems: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java But then again I don't know exactly how accurate grepcode is...

Answer (score 3):

- If additions to that `ArrayList` are really unlikely and if it's important to keep the size of the `ArrayList` at a minimum, then I can see that being useful.
- Or if the only purpose of that `ArrayList` is to be a return value from a method, where returning an empty list is a special message to the function caller, like "no results found".
- Otherwise, not really.

Answer (score 2):

By default `ArrayList` has capacity of [10](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.0elementData) and it is resized by +50% each time.

By using lower initial capacity you can *sometimes*(in theory) save memory. On the other hand each resize is time consuming. In most cases it is just a sign of preemptive optimization.

Comment: This is what I also thought, but having just checked the source of openjdk 7 it now optimises by using a shared empty element as described by @vikingsteve.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better approach to give a large value(if you how much list will exceed) to array list, because it will reduce resizing of list and hence optimize your execution time.

Initializing array list with value `0` create `Empty` array list which `reducing memory` if you know your list will not present more then `10` content's.

Comment: Yes it is right, instead of keeping `null` value in your array list initialize it by zeros.

Comment: Okay, I removed my downvote. Your answer is now much better, thank you for taking the time to edit it again.

Comment: @vikingsteve I like you helped me a lot to improve my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the contract you can avoid NullPointerExceptions by not having nulls. It is good practice in certain situations, see Effective Java by Joshua Bloch **Item 43: Return empty arrays or collections, not nulls**

Comment: Obviously, the question was not contrasting ArrayList<>() vs ArrayList<>(), but was asking for general reasons to use ArrayList<>(0). Sure, there are alternatives.